# Lenovo Yoga running Ubuntu arrow and volume key problems

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Yoga (2013) running Ubuntu 18.10. When I hold down any of the arrow keys or the volume rocker switch on the side it will often change from that key to repeating a number key. When I let go that number key continues to be repeated. It will only stop when I press another key. Pressing the arrow or volume key will give the correct action again after that. This problem repeats regularly.

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo's BIOS design for Yoga machines precludes it, or any Linux install. See https://news.lenovo.com/pressroom/press-releases/lenovo-statement-on-linux-support-for-yoga/. If it works at all, count your blessings.

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot.